# Member of subclass not found

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I think I have the problem of data slicing, but I don't know how to fix this.
Here I just have one subclass (B), but in reality I have other subclasses (which don't have `j` as a member).

This is my code:

helloworld.h

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H_
#define HELLOWORLD_H_

class A {
public:
    A(): i(5) {}
    int i;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B(): A(), j(2) {}
    int j;
};
#endif /* HELLOWORLD_H_ */
```

helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "helloworld.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new B());
    v.push_back(new B());
    vector<A*>::iterator it = v.begin();
    ++it;
    cout << (*it)->j;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing `vector<A*>` to `vector<B*>` is the obvious way to fix it. I could tell you something more useful but I'd need to know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: If you have other subclasses that don't have `j` as a member, then what do you expect `(*it)->j` to do?

Comment: I want that to return the value of `j` (2 here). I have a function that knows what to ask to which subtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from @interjay's comment:

C++ doesn't work that way. Your `A` class has no idea what type of variables child classes are going to have, so it can not access them. You could use virtual functions instead.

Header:

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H_
#define HELLOWORLD_H_

class A {
public:
    A(): i(5) {}

    virtual int GetJ () const = 0 ;

private:
    int i;
};

int A::GetJ () const {
    // Throw exception or return an error.
}

class B: public A {
public:
    B(): A(), j(2) {}

    int GetJ () const ;

private:
    int j;
};

int B::GetJ () const {
    return j ;
}

#endif /* HELLOWORLD_H_ */
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "helloworld.h"
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new B());
    v.push_back(new B());
    vector<A*>::iterator it = v.begin();
    cout << (*it)->GetJ () ;

    // Don't forget to clean up memory allocations,
    // or better yet, use smart pointers.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `const = 0` necessary (after `virtual int GetJ ()`)?

Comment: The `const` part is not necessary. It just says that the method doesn't change the class. The `= 0` says that this is a pure virtual function and subclasses must implement it.

Comment: All subclasses or at least one?

Comment: All non-abstract subclasses. [Read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

Comment: Is it possible to let some subclasses not define a virtual function?

Comment: You could just do `virtual int GetJ () const ;` without the `= 0`. Sorry for making it overly complicated.